# C# POCO Many-To-Many relationship, getting Tablename_Fieldname not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, many-to-many

I have a simple table structure of Company, Location, and a many-to-many CompanyLocation table, something like this:

```
create table Company 
(
    CompanyId bigint not null identity,
    CompanyName varchar(50),
    --other fields
    constraint PK_Company primary key (CompanyId)
)

create table Location
(
    LocationId int not null identity,
    LocationName varchar(50),
    --other fields
    constraint PK_Location primary key (LocationId)
)

create table CompanyLocation
(
    CompanyId bigint not null,
    LocationId int not null,
    constraint PK_CompanyLocation primary key (CompanyId, LocationId),
    constraint FK_CompanyLocation_Company foreign key (CompanyId) references Company(CompanyId),
    constraint FK_CompanyLocation_Location foreign key (LocationId) references Location(LocationId)
)
```

So my many-to-many table is a 'proper' key-only-table. My POCO classes are defined as such:

```
public class Company
{
    public long CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    //more fields

    public virtual List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    //more fields

    public virtual List<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

It compiles find, and when I run it, after I load a Company, if I access Company.Locations.anything, I get the following error:

```
Invalid column name 'Location_LocationID'.
Invalid column name 'Company_CompanyId'.
```

I know I can manually map these, but I'm trying to follow the Convention Over Configuration Entity Framework way of creating POCO many-to-many relationships. What have I done wrong with this model?

-shnar

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a join table with the Location_LocationID & Company_CompanyId fields in order to take advantage of the EF convention. Although I didn't manage to get this up and running with Fluent API mapping, I have tried and I'm stuck with the same error, like EF is ignoring my Fluent API mapping.

Regards

Comment: Well, my tables have foreign keys to each other, I thought EF was just supposed to "know" and do this mapping for us, by convention? I got this to work by manually forcing it and putting in [ForeignKey("LocationId")] attribute above the Location list, but I thought we didn't have to do this if we followed EF's convention?